# AVL Tree strange behavior

Tags: c++, avl-tree

The following code got me really puzzled.

class

```
class AVLTree {
   private:
struct AVLNode
{
    AVLNode *leftchild;
    AVLNode *rightchild;
    int data;
    int height;
};

AVLNode *root;

public:

AVLTree()
{
    root = NULL;
}

bool isEmpty() const { return root == NULL; }
void print();
void inorder(AVLNode *n, int l);
void insert(int d);
void rotateLeft(AVLNode* n);
void rotateRight(AVLNode* n);
void rotateLeftTwice(AVLNode* n);
void rotateRightTwice(AVLNode* n);
AVLTree::AVLNode* insert(int d, AVLNode* n);
int max( int a, int b);
int height( AVLNode* n); };
```

insert function.

```
  AVLTree::AVLNode* AVLTree::insert(int d,AVLNode *n){
    if (n == NULL)
    {
        AVLNode *n = new AVLNode;
        n->data = d;
        n->leftchild = NULL;
        n->rightchild = NULL;
        n->height = 0;
    } else if( d < n->data) {
        n->leftchild = insert(d,n->leftchild);

    } else if (d > n->data) {
        n->rightchild = insert(d,n->rightchild);
    }
    else {      
        n->height = max(height(n->leftchild), height(n->rightchild));
        return n;
         }
        -----> This section of the code gives be "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".
    n->height = max(height(n->leftchild), height(n->rightchild));
       return n;
}
```

This is the height function.

```
int AVLTree::height(AVLNode* node)
{   cout << "HEIGHT"; 
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return node->height;
    }
}
```

Anyone knows why?

=== Update:

when doing the rotation

```
 void AVLTree::rotateLeft(AVLNode* n)
    {
            AVLNode *child = n->leftchild;
            n->leftchild = child->rightchild;
            child->rightchild = n;

            n->height = max(height(n->leftchild),height(n->rightchild))+1;
            child->height = max(height(child->leftchild),height(child->rightchild))+1;
            n = child;
}
```

It seems not to be swapping values as it should. While n = child seems to swap locally it does not reflect a change i the rest of the code. Giving me an infinite loop.

Comment: What is your _specific_ question?

Comment: Have you stepped through the function using a debugger to see what is happening?

Comment: "The following code got me really puzzled. [...] Anyone knows why?" Hm...I'd say: "because you don't understand the code." Now, perhaps you can ask us more specifically about what you don't understand?

Comment: why does it give "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" after running it twice. Please read the insert function before commenting...

Comment: When you stepped through the function using your debugger, what happened before the EXC_BAD_ACCESS?  Were all of the pointers pointing to valid nodes?  Was there a null or otherwise invalid pointer being dereferenced?  If so, how did that pointer become null or invalid, or where did you forget to set it to point to a valid node?

Comment: James McNellis, even if pointer is null it should not give me an error since the height function does return either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `n` was null on entry to the function, then that line will attempt to dereference it, giving the error. Your code to allocate a new node should assign it to `n` itself, rather than a separate variable with the same name that shadows the function argument.

Change the first line of the `if (n == NULL)` block from

```
AVLNode *n = new AVLNode;
```

to

```
n = new AVLNode;
```

Regarding the update: In your rotate function, `n` is a local (automatic) variable, and changing that won't affect anything outside the function. You will need to either pass the pointer by reference, or return the new pointer value (like you do in `insert()`).

Comment: It really helped. But there is still something I am not sure about.